# Perforce P4 command line: How to list all submitted files since a certain date?

Tags: command-line, perforce

I want to create a list of all the files in a folder in perforce that were submitted past a certain date. I used the command line

```
p4 files -e [path to the folder in perforce] @[date] > [somefile.txt]
```

but this gave me every file in the depot, resulting in a 2gb txt file. Is the thing I want to do even possible with the 'p4 files' command?

I hope I've been clear enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you want is:

```
p4 files PATH@DATE,@now
```

e.g. if the date is 2016/02/02 and the path is //depot/main:

```
p4 files //depot/main/...@2016/02/02,@now > somefile.txt
```